# Why LIKE query isn't working in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query...

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE first_name LIKE '[aeiou]%';
```

The result is showing as:

```
EMPTY SET
```

Why it is so? Even when I am having enough entries in the table starting with aeiou? However, it's working fine for:

```
WHERE first_name LIKE 'C%';
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 4):

`LIKE` in MySQL doesn't support character sets like `[aeiou]`. The only patterns it has is `%` to match any number of characters, and `_` to match any single character.

You need to use a regular expression:

```
WHERE first_name REGEX '^[aeiou]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check any matching record starting with any of vowel then use below one

```
SELECT first_name 
FROM   customers
WHERE  first_name RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Comment: what .* signifies ?? is it concate ? I mean is it checking two conditions like begins with a vowel and ends with a vowel?